# Using “<>” logic in an Excel Sumifs formula.

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I apologize in advance if my question is unclear. It’s my first time posting on this forum. I’m trying to write a Sumifs formula in Excel where one of the criteria is to sum everything **except** a specific value. I write a small amount in SQL and i use the <> function to eliminate specific values. Is there a similar ability in Excel? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `SUMIF()` or `SUMIFS()`, you can use `<>`:

```
=SUMIFS($A$1:$A$100,$B$1:$B$100,"<>123")
```

That will check if a value in your `B1:B100` range is `123`, and if so, will *not* use that equivalent value in the `A1:A100` range.

Comment: Bless you, my caped crusader savior!  You've saved me hours of grunt work and I do not think I am exaggerating!

Comment: @user9174444 - Glad it worked!  You can mark this as The Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post (below the down arrow), if it's the solution you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Excel has a NOT function.

So, you would say

```
=NOT(A2="yourtest")
```

In this case, it means it returns true if A2 is not the string "your test"

Answer (score 0):

I think that maybe your syntax for the criteria is not correct.
This formula works to exclude the string "A" from the summed results...

```
    =SUMIF($A$1:$A$6,"<>A",$B$1:$B$6)
```

If you are trying to exclude "A" by referencing a cell that "A" is stored, this will not work.  For example

```
    =SUMIF($A$1:$A$6,"<>E1",$B$1:$B$6)
```

Here is a working example in excel:

[image]

Comment: .....but if you do want to use the cell reference the syntax is like this: `=SUMIF($A$1:$A$6,"<>"&E2,$B$1:$B$6)`

Comment: Excellent. Thanks @barry houdini